# How to put data from server to Kinesis Stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-kinesis

I am new to Kinesis. Reading out the documentation i found i can create the Kinesis Stream to get data from Producer. Then using KCL will read this data from Stream to further processing. I understand how to write the KCL application by implemeting IRecordProcessor .

However the very first stage as how to put data on Kinesis stream is still not clear to me. Do we have some AWS API which does need implementation to achieve this.

Scenarios: I have an server which is contineously getting data from various sources in the folders. Each folder is containing the text file whose rows are containing the required attributes for furhter analytical work. i have to push all these data to Kinesis Stream.

I need code something as below below class putData method wil be used to out in Kinesis stream

```
public class Put {

    AmazonKinesisClient kinesisClient;

    Put()
    {
        String accessKey = "My Access Key here" ;
        String secretKey = "My Secret Key here" ;
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
       kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials);
       kinesisClient.setEndpoint("kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "kinesis", "us-east-1");
        System.out.println("starting the Put Application");
    }

    public void putData(String fileContent,String session) throws Exception
    {
         final String myStreamName = "ClickStream";

            PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
            putRecordRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName);
            String putData = fileContent;
            putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(putData.getBytes()));
            putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey("session"+session);
            PutRecordResult putRecordResult = kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
            System.out.println("Successfully putrecord, partition key : " + putRecordRequest.getPartitionKey()
                    + ", ShardID : " + putRecordResult.getShardId());
            System.out.println(fileContent);
            System.out.println("Sequence Number: "+putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());

            System.out.println("Data has been PUT successfully");


    }
}
```

However reading file from the source folder from the server and then what design i should use to call putData to get the record on Kinesis stream. Do i need infinite loop and reading all files and then do this or some framework which will better do this with care of fault tolerance , single point of failure all . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Briefly: I need a better technique to put regularly generated data to Kinesis Stream the data is generated at regular interval to server. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you are already using...
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/AmazonKinesisClient.html

Specific method you want is as follows.

You need a stream name, record, and stream key. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/model/PutRecordResult.html

But it seems you have all this?

You would then need a program running always tailing your server log file and when ever there is a new line it will push this.

But your data will only sit their for 24 hours. You then need a worker program to consume the data and place it in some other AWS resource.

Comment: Yes i am moving data to S3 from Kinesis. I was looking some ready made solution to keep reading the files from the folder from my server for each day and put all these data to Kinesis stream. Well in my server i have multiple folder for different date and each day contains many files with log information. i want to transfer this to Kinesis stream. At this level i think i can write simple program with infinite loop with some thread delay to keep reading the events  and move to Kinesis if some already proven solution is not present. Thanks

Comment: May i use RabbitMQ to put data to Kinesis Stream. ?

Comment: Amazon does not provide any out of the box pushing program. You must create it yourself. No fimiliar with RabbitMQ

Comment: With Java7 interesting feature of WatchService API is great to deal with my file problems. Now i am able to read files as on when created\changed etc. However could you please recommend me some good tips to choose partition key. ?

Comment: Think of a deck of cards, an okay partition key would be color, but a better one would be suits. It depends on your data, but I have used things like EventType, UserID, Country+StateofRecord. You want to try and split your data evenly amoung readers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are tailing some files, try Fluentd. http://www.fluentd.org/

Amazon Kinesis has a pretty nice plugin for that. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-fluent-plugin-kinesis

Answer (score 2):

You can use Amazon kinesis agent to monitor on a set of files and they can stream data to kinesis.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to ingest log files, please try Fluentd. Fluentd can tail log files continuously, and do data buffering, encryption, compression, and retry.

- http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/kinesis-stream

Fluentd's Kinesis plugin is developed by Amazon Web Services itself.